# When Center of group is a subset of Normalizer($Z(G) \subset N(a)$).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

**DEFINITION:**

If $a \in G$, then $N(a)$, the normalizer of $a$ in $G$, is the set
$N (a) =  \{ x \in G | xa = ax \} $.

$Z(G)$ is the center of the group.

I found the following proof -

> **Lemma:**  If $|G| = p^2$ where p is a prime number, then G is abelian.
>
> **Proof:** The  aim is to show that $Z(G) = G$.
>
> At any rate, we know that $Z(G) \neq  e$ is a subgroup of G so that
>   $|Z(G)| = p $ or $ p^2 $ .
>
> If $|Z(G)|= p^2$ , then $Z(G) = G$ and we are done.
>
> Suppose that $|Z(G)| = p$; let $a \in G, a \notin Z(G)$. Thus
>   $N(a)$  is a subgroup of $G, Z(G) \subset  N(a)$,
>
> $ a \in  N(a)$ , so that $| N(a)| > p$, yet by Lagrange's theorem
>   $|N(a)| \mid |G| = p^2$ . The only way out is for $|N(a)| = p^ 2 $,
>   implying that $a \in Z(G)$, a contradiction. Thus $|Z(G)|$ =p is not
>   an actual possibility.$\blacksquare$
>
> -Topics in Algebra(2nd-edition-1975) by Herstein, page 84.

**Question:** Why $Z(G) \subset  N(a)$ ?  or how it is derived ?

Comment: The definition given for $N(a)$ here is what is usually called the *centralizer* of $a$; although it is correct to call it the normalizer of the singleton set $\{a\}$, I'm not sure what is gained by thinking about it this way...

Comment: It is written as it was found.

Comment: I don't doubt that. I'm not questioning what you've written; I'm questioning the author's intentions. I'm sure you'll learn about centralizers and normalizers in more detail over time, then maybe you will look back at this question and wonder about the exact same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$Z(G) = \{x \in G : gx = xg \textrm{ } \forall g \in G \}$. Hence, if $x \in Z(G)$ then $xa = ax$ i.e. $x \in N(a)$.